# Labeling node on extended line with shorten option

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code and the result are follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-euclide,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings,float,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,patterns,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,intersections,through,backgrounds,fit,arrows.meta}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]\tiny
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw [-latex,very thick] (-1,0)--(6,0)coordinate(X) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw [-latex,very thick] (0,-1)--(0,5)coordinate(Y) node[left]{$y$};
   \node at (O) [below left]{$O$};
   \fill (1,1)coordinate (q1) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_1$};
   \fill (2,3)coordinate (q2) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_2$};
   \fill (3,4)coordinate (q3) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_3$};
   \fill (5,3.5)coordinate (qn) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_n$};
   \fill (4,1.25)coordinate (P) circle (2pt)node[above=1.5mm, right=1mm]{$P$};
   \draw [shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm,dotted,thick] (q3) to [bend left=6](qn);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,n}{  
   \draw [-latex, shorten >= -0.7500cm](q\i)--(P)node[midway,sloped,above]{$\mathbf{D}_{\i}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to put two labels on my each vector. The first one is Di (say D1, D2, etc. as seen in my figure), second one is end of the extend, such as E1, E2, E3 and En. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node [midway] {$D_{\i}$}` is really `node [pos=0.5] {$D_{\i}$}` which places the node half way along.  It's maybe not the optimal method when `shorten=` takes a length but the same method can be used for the labels at the end.  The `pos=` key functions as might be expected for values outside of `0-1`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-euclide,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings,float,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,patterns,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,intersections,through,backgrounds,fit,arrows.meta}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]\tiny
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw [-latex,very thick] (-1,0)--(6,0)coordinate(X) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw [-latex,very thick] (0,-1)--(0,5)coordinate(Y) node[left]{$y$};
   \node at (O) [below left]{$O$};
   \fill (1,1)coordinate (q1) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_1$};
   \fill (2,3)coordinate (q2) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_2$};
   \fill (3,4)coordinate (q3) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_3$};
   \fill (5,3.5)coordinate (qn) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_n$};
   \fill (4,1.25)coordinate (P) circle (2pt)node[above=1.5mm, right=1mm]{$P$};
   \draw [shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm,dotted,thick] (q3) to [bend left=6](qn);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,n}{  
   \draw [-latex, shorten >= -0.7500cm](q\i)--(P)node[midway,sloped,above]{$\mathbf{D}_{\i}$} node [pos=1.375] {$E_{\i}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Dai Bowen's answer is easier and more convenient, this is just to show an alternative method using the syntax of the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]\tiny
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw [-latex,very thick] (-1,0)--(6,0)coordinate(X) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw [-latex,very thick] (0,-1)--(0,5)coordinate(Y) node[left]{$y$};
   \node at (O) [below left]{$O$};
   \fill (1,1)coordinate (q1) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_1$};
   \fill (2,3)coordinate (q2) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_2$};
   \fill (3,4)coordinate (q3) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_3$};
   \fill (5,3.5)coordinate (qn) circle (2pt)node[left]{$q_n$};
   \fill (4,1.25)coordinate (P) circle (2pt)node[above=1.5mm, right=1mm]{$P$};
   \draw [shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm,dotted,thick] (q3) to [bend left=6](qn);
   \foreach \i in {1,2,3,n}{  
      \draw [-latex](q\i)--($(P)!-0.75cm!(q\i)$)
             node[midway,sloped,above]{$\mathbf{D}_{\i}$}; 
      \node at ($(P)!-1cm!(q\i)$) {$E_\i$};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the better method given `shorten` expects a length and `pos` a ratio.  `\node at ($(P)!-1cm!(q\i)$) {$E_\i$};` works with  `\draw [-latex, shorten >= -0.7500cm](q\i)--(P)` just as well as `\draw [-latex](q\i)--($(P)!-0.75cm!(q\i)$)` if use of the `shorten` option is preferred.